# Render webpage into an image using Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, image, air, rendering

I want to render a webpage into a small thumbnail image in an Adobe Flex application. 
Does anyone know of a method to do this?

Comment: Are you creating an AIR application or publishing for the web? If you are publishing for the web, there is no way for the Flash plugin to visually capture the contents of the whole webpage.

Comment: You'll need a serverside to do that. What are you using on the backend?